# How to mine Dogecoin on Ubuntu?

Tags: application-development, services, system, compatibility

I have a question for the community. What is your best advice for mining dogecoin on Ubuntu? I have searched on youtube and found this video. Link below. What is your advice for mining!
Link: https://youtu.be/Ng-OU38-RjY
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

My advice on mining is this:

From [Dogecoin's wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogecoin), I have learned that it's a [proof-of-work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_work) based system, just like bitcoin is.

This means that both bitcoin's and doge's working principle is to **waste incredibly huge amounts of computing power throughout worldwide networks in every minute of every hour**. (That's what a proof-of-work system is: computers need to prove among each other who won in competitions of solving entirely senseless exercises that were designed specifically to be difficult, and thus, wasteful.)

1. The energy for this must come from somewhere; we are now seeing "some improvement", because coal powerplants — and maybe, maybe slowly other fossil-fuel based power sources — are getting on the path of being phased out (or at least, losing from their prominence), but the price for that is that we now deface all of our landscapes with wind-power generators that chop up birds (and when they are sea-based, they additionally disrupt sea habitats during their construction), solar energy farms that occupy and deface hundreds, and altogether, who knows how many thousands of acres of land, and also start to install tidal power generators in our seas that chop up fish.
2. Furthermore, mining farms need cooling, so either that consumes more energy, or they put the mining farm somewhere near the Arctic, and call it sustainable, because the cooling power does not need to come from electricity: they simply let the surrounding environment dissipate the heat.

   - But my concern with that is the extra heat: it's nice that they did not need additional wind-generators to achieve *the cooling*, but the heat radiating from the mining farm still contributes to heating the arctic region, and thus, to global warming.

     - (Please could someone confirm or counter this claim?)

Now, I am aware that we would be building these wind-, solar-, and tidal-power farms anyways, but the point is that due to crypto (and, btw. also due to 4K media streaming) *we need to build more of these things than we would otherwise need to*.

Based on these considerations, I offer that *please*, consider not only not mining, but not using at all proof-of-work based cryptocurrencies.

Comment: Okay, at a closer look at the [proof-of-work principle's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_work), now I can see that: "The purpose of proof-of-work algorithms are not proving that certain work was carried out or that a computational puzzle was "solved", but deterring manipulation of data via the specific solution of establishing large energy and hardware-control requirements for the ability to do so." — So while the exact utilization of the energy wastage is different from how I described it, it does not change anything about the amount of energy wasted.